# Button to show/hide Booking Form on wp

Tags: html, wordpress, css, hide, show

i modify an hotel theme website on Wordpress, i added a button on the header part and want it to show a simplebooking form that i already have, i just need to know what i have to do to make it work any tutorial please or ideas? now 2 days and still looking for a method to get it done, still searching.
Thanks everyone,

```
<div class="col-md-7 alignright"><a href=""><button class="apb-btn" style="margin-top:25px; border-radius:0px !important; background-color:#f3d339 !important;">CHECK AVAILABILITY</button></a>
```

Comment: you want to open the form on button click?

Comment: Hi @MohitShah , yesit will look good on mobile screen i'm searching for a method to know how to do it

Comment: Do you want to open it in same page or new page?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MohitShah , yes on the same page its a wp theme i tried to follow one tuto but i had js conflict not working.

Comment: can you share the code in fiddle?

Comment: hi mr @MohitShah , the js code that i added is 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.visible').hide();
});

$("#main_book").click(function(){
$(".visible").show();
});   but still showing at first i need it to show after click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //you should add class name for link to not target all links with click event
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(".apb-btn").toggle();
    });
});
```

If you have jquery library you can do this

https://jsfiddle.net/ak7tj4m7/2/

Comment: Hi mr @varto yes i'm using a div with(-450px) that have to show after clicking the button i used 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.visible').hide();
});

$("#main_book").click(function(){
$(".visible").show();
});               but still not working even after trying also the method you told me, thanks

Comment: Still showing (#main_book) as first element i need it to show after click on the button thats why

Comment: you need add also width to be in the screen so if it is -450px bring it back to 0 or some positive value to be visible on the screen.

Comment: yes mr @varto for the css part is good, now it my button <a onclick="">
                <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span>
                <span>Book now</span>
            </a>   have to show the element when clicked  $("#main_book").click(function(){ $(".visible").show(); }); but the problem it shows before clicking

Comment: <a class="my-book-now-button"> <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span> <span>Book now</span> </a>                          
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".my-book-now-button").click(function(){
        $(this).toggle();
    });
});

Comment: i tried this but still same by class="my-book-now-button" you mean the .visible class that i gave to my element right?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eve0eL98/ Just use your class name to target element that you wanna click and that you wanna hide is this what you want ? btw you need to add in `<head></head>` jquery library to be able to use jquery did you forgot that maybe ?

Comment: thanks for giving me your time sir @varto , no what i'm working on is like the "book now" in this http://www.pickalbatros.com/ that i found

Comment: So you want on click hide button and display menu that comes from right side?

Comment: Yes sir, when book now the right side have to show then we can hide it using the close button

Comment: Thank you very much mr @varto i followed the instructions but i had some minor problems that a friend solved for me, and he will come to show me what i missed